# Xamarin Android - Load url in second webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

Hi I wanted to load up a webview on android. And when a link is clicked in this webview to override the loading and have the link load in another webview. So I can display the first webview without having to reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

1. set a custom webview client on your webview
   `webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient(this));`
2. In your webview client override `ShouldInterceptRequest`
3. In `ShouldInterceptRequest` method use the url parameter to create/show a new webview and then just return the current displayed data to prevent loading a new webview.